# eval function in javascript and decimal number

Tags: javascript, eval

When I call this function `f = new Function("return 2.3*3;")` I get 6.8999999999999995 instead of 6.9. How to have the exact result?

Comment: May I ask why you are using `eval`?

Comment: `eval`... Yuck!

Comment: I changed with Function

Answer (score 2):

Use toFixed function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

```js
    var num = eval("2.3*3")
console.log(num.toFixed(1))
```